# Woocommerce order confirmation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store with few shipping methods. Is there any plugin that after a customer places a order that needs physical shipping, to ask customer to confirm his order by email?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming when the customer buys something there's no real decision behind it?

Comment: Yes. That already happend a few times. Customer ordered and after shipping the customer didn't collected the package and returned back.

Comment: How can add another confirmation grant you that same problem wont happen again?

Comment: It can't, nor phone confirmation can. But when i have a boss with square head i need to explore all options...

Comment: Gonna investigate and keep you posted.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." You need to do the proper research and see if you can find any plugin that does what you want. If you can't find any, you'll need to build your own.

Answer (score 1):

After research found some plugins / extensions that can be of use to you, namely:

1. [WooCommerce 'Email Money Transfer' Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-email-money-transfer-gateway/);
2. [Moneris Gateway](https://woocommerce.com/products/moneris-gateway/).

It doesn't directly work as you mention but the process has similarities.